# fisher's linear discriminant in Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, math, statistics

I have the fisher's linear discriminant that i need to use it to reduce my examples A and B that are high dimensional matrices to simply 2D, that is exactly like LDA, each example has classes A and B, therefore if i was to have a third example they also have classes A and B, fourth, fifth and n examples would always have classes A and B, therefore i would like to separate them in a simple use of fisher's linear discriminant. Im pretty much new to machine learning, so i dont know how to separate my classes, i've been following the formula by eye and coding on the go. From what i was reading, i need to apply a linear transformation to my data so i can find a good threshold for it, but first i'd need to  find the maximization function. For such task, i managed to find Sw and Sb, but i don't know how to go from there...

[image]

Where i also need to find the maximization function.

[image]

That maximization function gives me an eigen value solution:

[image]

What i have for each classes are matrices 5x2 of 2 examples. For instance:

```
Example 1 
Class_A = [
201, 103,
40, 43,
23, 50,
12, 123,
99, 78
]
Class_B = [
   201, 129,
   114, 195,
   180, 90,
   69, 62,
   76, 90
]

Example 2   
Class_A = [
68, 98,
201, 203,
78, 212,
49, 5,
204, 78
]   
Class_B = [
   52, 19,
   220, 219,
   159, 195,
   99, 23,
   46, 50
]
```

I tried finding Sw for the example above like this:

```
Example_1_Class_A = np.dot(Example_1_Class_A,  np.transpose(Example_1_Class_A))
Example_1_Class_B = np.dot(Example_1_Class_B,  np.transpose(Example_1_Class_B))

Example_2_Class_A = np.dot(Example_2_Class_A,  np.transpose(Example_2_Class_A))
Example_2_Class_B = np.dot(Example_2_Class_B,  np.transpose(Example_2_Class_B))

Sw = sum([Example_1_Class_A, Example_1_Class_B, Example_2_Class_A, Example_2_Class_B], axis=0)
```

As for Sb, i tried like this:

```
Example_1_Class_A_mean = Example_1_Class_A.mean(axis=0)
Example_1_Class_B_mean = Example_1_Class_B.mean(axis=0)
         
Example_2_Class_A_mean = Example_2_Class_A.mean(axis=0)
Example_2_Class_B_mean = Example_2_Class_B.mean(axis=0)
         
Example_1_Class_A_Sb = np.dot(Example_1_Class_A_mean, np.transpose(Example_1_Class_A_mean))
Example_1_Class_B_Sb = np.dot(Example_1_Class_B_mean, np.transpose(Example_1_Class_B_mean))
         
Example_2_Class_A_Sb = np.dot(Example_2_Class_A_mean, np.transpose(Example_2_Class_A_mean))
Example_2_Class_B_Sb = np.dot(Example_2_Class_B_mean, np.transpose(Example_2_Class_B_mean))
Sb = sum([Example_1_Class_A_Sb, Example_1_Class_B_Sb, Example_2_Class_A_Sb, Example_2_Class_B_Sb], axis=0)
```

The problem is, i have no idea what else to do with my Sw and Sb, i am completely lost. Basically, what i need to do is get from here to this:

[image]

How for given Example A and Example B, do i separate a cluster only for classes As and only for classes b

Comment: Your question is unclear, but I think you should solve the maths behind it firstly, then implement it. Then if you get any error, then ask. And clearly show the mathematics here too.

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma The question is simply how to implement fisher's linear discriminant with those arrays size specifically and those arrays are a reproducible example from what i was trying. My actual matrices are 50x20 for each class and i have 8 examples. The maths you suggest me to add aren't exactly clear, because i am showing the calculation im doing, explicitly, so i dont know which maths, you would like me to add

Comment: What do you want to do with Sw and Sb? Thats with maths. Implement what you want to do next, then if you get ant error, then ask. Because in the code you have implemented till now, there is no error.

Comment: That is exactly the question, for the given data where i calculate Sw and Sb, how do i extract the eigenvectors and eigen values to reduce my data to 2D? i dont know how to do that.

Comment: For eigenvectors and eigenvalues, use scipy library [link](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~pwalls/math-python/linear-algebra/eigenvalues-eigenvectors/).

Comment: For transforming 3D data to 2D, use Principal Component Analysis(PCA), [link](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_pca_step_by_step.html) or [link2](https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-using-python-scikit-learn-e653f8989e60)

Comment: It needs to be fisher's linear discriminant, i know about scipy's eigen vector but how do i use it for my data?

Comment: The data isn't 3D though.

Comment: Well, you provide only 2D, data (5 observations with 2 dimensions each per class and example). This does not work well if you want to reduce the dimensions. However, I can show an example how to do it with iris dataset, and explain the math behind each step. If that's ok for you. The procedure is portable to your data, of course

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before answering your question, I will first touch the basic difference between PCA and (F)LDA. In PCA you don't know anything about underlying classes, but you **assume** that the information about classes separability lies in the variance of data. So you rotate your original axes (sometimes it is called projecting all the data onto new ones) in such way that your first new axis is pointing to the direction of most variance, second one is perpendicular to the first one and pointing to the direction of most **residiual** variance, and so on. This way a PCA transformation results in a (sub)space of the same dimensionality as the original one. Than you can take only first 2 dimensions, rejecting the rest, hence getting a dimensionality reduction from *k* dimensions to only 2.

LDA works a bit differently. In this case you know in advance how many classes there are in your data, and you can find their mean and covariance matrices. What Fisher criterion does it finds a direction in which the mean between classes is maximized, while **at the same time** total variability is minimized (total variability is a mean of within-class covariance matrices). And for each two classes there is only one such line. This is why when your data has *C* classes, LDA can provide you at most *C-1* dimensions, regardless of the original data dimensionality. In your case this means that as you have only 2 classes A and B, you will get a one-dimensional projection, i.e. a line. And this is exactly what you have in your picture: original 2d data is projected on to a line. The direction of the line is the solution of the eigenproblem.
Let's generate data that is similar to your picture:

```
a = np.random.multivariate_normal((1.5, 3), [[0.5, 0], [0, .05]], 30)
b = np.random.multivariate_normal((4, 1.5), [[0.5, 0], [0, .05]], 30)
plt.plot(a[:,0], a[:,1], 'b.', b[:,0], b[:,1], 'r.')
mu_a, mu_b = a.mean(axis=0).reshape(-1,1), b.mean(axis=0).reshape(-1,1)
Sw = np.cov(a.T) + np.cov(b.T)
inv_S = np.linalg.inv(Sw)
res = inv_S.dot(mu_a-mu_b)  # the trick
####
# more general solution
#
# Sb = (mu_a-mu_b)*((mu_a-mu_b).T)
# eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(inv_S.dot(Sb))
# res = sorted(zip(eig_vals, eig_vecs), reverse=True)[0][1] # take only eigenvec corresponding to largest (and the only one) eigenvalue
# res = res / np.linalg.norm(res)

plt.plot([-res[0], res[0]], [-res[1], res[1]]) # this is the solution
plt.plot(mu_a[0], mu_a[1], 'cx')
plt.plot(mu_b[0], mu_b[1], 'yx')
plt.gca().axis('square')

# let's project data point on it
r = res.reshape(2,)
n2 = np.linalg.norm(r)**2
for pt in a:
    prj = r * r.dot(pt) / n2
    plt.plot([prj[0], pt[0]], [prj[1], pt[1]], 'b.:', alpha=0.2)
for pt in b:
    prj = r * r.dot(pt) / n2
    plt.plot([prj[0], pt[0]], [prj[1], pt[1]], 'r.:', alpha=0.2)
```

The resulting projection is calculated using a neat trick for two class problem. You can read details on it [here in section 1.6](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/wujx/teaching/06_FLD.pdf).

[image]

Regarding the "examples" you mention in your question. I believe you need to repeat the process for each example, as it is a different set of data point probably with different distributions. Also, put attention that estimated mean (mu_a, mu_b) and class covariance matrices would be slightly different from the ones that data was generated with, especially for small sample size.

Answer (score 10):

### Mathematics

[image]

See https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_lda.html#lda-in-5-steps for more information.

### Implementation using Iris

Since you want to use LDA for dimensionality reduction but provide only 2d data I am showing how to perform this procedure on the iris dataset.

#### Let's import libraries

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import sklearn as sk
    from collections import Counter
    from sklearn import datasets
    
    # load dataset and transform to pandas df
    X, y = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)
    X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'feat_{i}' for i in range(4)])
    y = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['labels'])
    tot = pd.concat([X,y], axis=1)
    # calculate class means
    class_means = tot.groupby('labels').mean()
    total_mean = X.mean()
```

The `class_means` are given by:

```py
class_means

    feat_0  feat_1  feat_2  feat_3
labels              
0   5.006   3.428   1.462   0.246
1   5.936   2.770   4.260   1.326
2   6.588   2.974   5.552   2.026
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

To do this, we first subtract the class means from each observation (basically we calculate `x - m_i` from the equation above).
Subtract the corresponding class mean from each observation. Since we want to calculate

```py
x_mi = tot.transform(lambda x: x - class_means.loc[x['labels']], axis=1).drop('labels', 1)

def kronecker_and_sum(df, weights):
    S = np.zeros((df.shape[1], df.shape[1]))
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        x_m = row.as_matrix().reshape(df.shape[1],1)
        S += weights[idx]*np.dot(x_m, x_m.T)
    return S

# Each x_mi is weighted with 1. Now we use the kronecker_and_sum function to calculate the within-class scatter matrix S_w
S_w = kronecker_and_sum(x_mi, 150*[1])
```

[image: adfadfs]

```py
mi_m = class_means.transform(lambda x: x - total_mean, axis=1)
# Each mi_m is weighted with the number of observations per class which is 50 for each class in this example. We use kronecker_and_sum to calculate the between-class scatter matrix.

S_b=kronecker_and_sum(mi_m, 3*[50])
```

[image]

```
eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(np.linalg.inv(S_w).dot(S_b))
```

We only need to consider the eigenvalues which are remarkably different from zero (in this case only the first two)

```
eig_vals
array([ 3.21919292e+01,  2.85391043e-01,  6.53468167e-15, -2.24877550e-15])
```

Transform `X` with the matrix of the two eigenvectors which correspond to the highest eigenvalues

```py
    W = eig_vecs[:, :2]
    X_trafo = np.dot(X, W)
    tot_trafo = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X_trafo, index=range(len(X_trafo))), y], 1)
    # plot the result
    tot_trafo.plot.scatter(x=0, y=1, c='labels', colormap='viridis')
```

[image]
We have reduced the dimensions from 4 to 2 and chosen the space in such a way, that the classes can be well seperated.

#### Scikit-learn usage

Scikit has LDA support aswell. What we did in dozens of lines can be done with the following lines of code:

```
from sklearn import discriminant_analysis
lda = discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
X_trafo_sk = lda.fit_transform(X,y)
pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((X_trafo_sk, y))).plot.scatter(x=0, y=1, c=2, colormap='viridis')
```

I'm not giving a plot here, cause it is the same as in our derived example (except for a 180 degree rotation).

Comment: Sure you can only use this as classification, but that actually does not work well for the example you gave because this is not seperable with a linear function. If you just follow the procedure I outlined, you can verify this.

Comment: @xnok FDA is just a 2 class version of more general n-classes LDA. It does not forces you to classify data. It takes the information about different classes into account, to find a projection that will contribute most when you will classify the new data.

Comment: The projection output is used for classification, besides some source that is given for explaining the difference between both is here: https://youtu.be/hGKt0yy9q_E?t=3010. Furthermore, i have accomplished such task using 2D arrays