# Projecting multiple clusters for 2D data using the heighest eigen values from FLD

Tags: python, machine-learning, math, statistics, dimensionality-reduction

I have 4 matrices of size 5x5, where the five rows (5xn) are datapoints and the columns (nx5) are the features. As it follows:

```
datapoint_1_class_A = np.asarray([(216, 236, 235, 230, 229), (237, 192, 191, 193, 199), (218, 189, 191, 192, 193), (201, 239, 230, 229, 220), (237, 210, 200, 236, 235)])
datapoint_2_class_A = np.asarray([(202, 202, 201, 203, 204), (210, 211, 213, 209, 208), (203, 206, 202, 201, 199), (201, 207, 206, 199, 205), (190, 191, 192, 193, 194)])

datapoint_1_class_B = np.asarray([(236, 237, 238, 239, 240), (215, 216, 217, 218, 219), (201, 202, 203, 209, 210), (240, 241, 243, 244, 245), (220, 221, 222, 231, 242)])
datapoint_2_class_B = np.asarray([(242, 243, 245, 246, 247), (248, 249, 250, 251, 252), (210, 203, 209, 210, 211), (247, 248, 249, 250, 251), (230, 231, 235, 236, 240)])
```

First two matrices belong to class A and the last two matrices belongs to class B.

I am maximizing their separation by calculating the scatter within matrix (Sw) and scatter between matrix (Sb) and then extracting the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors.

Then, after the calculation i obtain the following eigen vectors and eigen values:

```
[(6551.009980205623, array([-0.4   ,  0.2531,  0.2835, -0.6809,  0.4816])), 
 (796.0735165617085, array([-0.4166, -0.4205,  0.6121, -0.2403,  0.4661])), 
 (4.423499174324943, array([ 0.1821, -0.1644,  0.7652, -0.2183, -0.5538])), 
 (1.4238024863819319, array([ 0.0702, -0.5216,  0.3792,  0.5736, -0.5002])), 
 (0.07624674030991384, array([ 0.2903, -0.2902,  0.2339, -0.73  ,  0.4938]))]
```

Aftwards i multiply the W matrix by the initial 20x5 matrix:

My W matrix gives me the following matrix:

Matrix W:

```
 [[-0.4,   -0.4166]
 [ 0.2531, -0.4205]
 [ 0.2835,  0.6121]
 [-0.6809, -0.2403]
 [ 0.4816,  0.4661]]

X_lda = X.dot(W)
```

and plot my data

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
plt.xlabel('LD1')
plt.ylabel('LD2')
plt.scatter(
    X_lda.iloc[:,0],
    X_lda.iloc[:,1],
    c=['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red'],
    cmap='rainbow',
    alpha=1,
    edgecolors='w'
)
```

The problem with this plot is that the data isn't exactly well clustered and separated, i was expecting the  datapoints to be clustered for each matrix and this is what i am getting from the above code:

This data doesn't look well clustered according to the plot axis, where their X and y axis are 5 and -5. My goal is to use the two highest eigen values: `6551.009980205623, 796.0735165617085` to plot my data inside a feature space (plot) that is exactly a cluster size (5x5), therefore the axes being 5, 5 in X and y respectively, where each point inside a cluster is very next to each other and their distance is very large.

Comment: what is the difference between `datapoint_1_class_A` and `datapoint_2_class_A`? Why not combine them into a single matrix with ten rows?

Comment: And, why do you have two different linear discriminants? What data was used to calculate the separate LDs? My assumption would be that you're looking for a single LD to best separate class A from class B. Are you actually looking to separate each of the four datasets from each other? In that case you should have `n*(n-1)/2 == 6` LDs, not `2`.

Comment: Ok, so i changed the names for better understanding. The goal is to classify two clusters A and B inside the same dimensional space, that is the 2D space. We have classes 0 and 1, where clusters A and B will need linear discriminants to separate their classes. Eventually i will have cluster C that will need to be discriminated for class 0 and 1, same thing will happen for cluster D and any new other clusters. They will always have the same amount of datapoints and same dimension.

Comment: As for the data used to calculate their separability was the sum of the standard deviation for each data_point for the scatter within matrix, as for the scatter between the matrix it was used the sum of the mean of each data_point.  Where, after finding the standard deviation for a datapoint, you'd need to multiply it by its inverse for all the datapoints, just then sum the results, same process for the mean value calculation, then just find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors by solving the generalizing problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is some mistake in your matrix calculations. You have 4 classes (datapoint_1_class_A, datapoint_2_class_A, datapoint_1_class_B, datapoint_2_class_B), so the rank of `W` might be maximum 3. You've got full rank, which is impossible. The last two eigenvalues should be around 1e-15.

Next, you have probably mixed your features and points dimensions. Please make sure that each row of `X` correspond to the **point**. Run a simple check: for each cluster find it's mean (by each column/feature). Add this point to the cluster. This will make your matrices being 6 points by 5 features. Now, find the mean again. You should get exactly the same result.

See following code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
a1 = np.asarray([(216, 236, 235, 230, 229), (237, 192, 191, 193, 199), (218, 189, 191, 192, 193), (201, 239, 230, 229, 220), (237, 210, 200, 236, 235)])
a2 = np.asarray([(202, 202, 201, 203, 204), (210, 211, 213, 209, 208), (203, 206, 202, 201, 199), (201, 207, 206, 199, 205), (190, 191, 192, 193, 194)])

b1 = np.asarray([(236, 237, 238, 239, 240), (215, 216, 217, 218, 219), (201, 202, 203, 209, 210), (240, 241, 243, 244, 245), (220, 221, 222, 231, 242)])
b2 = np.asarray([(242, 243, 245, 246, 247), (248, 249, 250, 251, 252), (210, 203, 209, 210, 211), (247, 248, 249, 250, 251), (230, 231, 235, 236, 240)])

X = np.vstack([a1.T, a2.T, b1.T, b2.T])
y = [1]*5 + [2]*5 + [3]*5 + [4]*5
clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
clf.fit(X, y)

Xem = clf.transform(X)
plt.scatter(Xem[0:5,0], Xem[0:5,1], c='b', marker='o')
plt.scatter(Xem[5:10,0], Xem[5:10,1], c='b', marker='s')
plt.scatter(Xem[10:15,0], Xem[10:15,1], c='r', marker='o')
plt.scatter(Xem[15:20,0], Xem[15:20,1], c='r', marker='s')
```

This results in following:[image: LDA transformed data]

Comment: If this implementation works, then this is ultimately the right solution for the question

Comment: Anyways, I run code with your data. It works ok, so no mistakes there. If you plot transformed data for each person separately, you will see that for 5 persons out of 8 there is a good separation between drunk and sober data. For real life dataset it is not that bad ;)

Comment: not exactly, still had bad separation, but thanks a bunch for your help, it was of great value in fact.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks similar to singular value decomposition, which attempts to condense high dimensional space into a smaller dimensional space by preserving the eigenvectors which best capture the spread of data.

This has been a popular strategy for a while, however, it has it's limitations: by only accounting for the projection of high dimensional space into a lower dimension, you necessarily fail to take into account the subtle spacial relationships that existed in the high dimensional representation.

A popular alternative is t-sne, which uses a loss function to iteratively optimize for the preservation of "closeness" in high dimensional data represented in lower dimensions. [this is a great video explaining t-sne and it's benefits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJVL80Gg3lA&t=1450s).

ultimately, though when using any clustering algorithm, you only get the separation that actually exists in your data, not the one that you want. It's entirely possible that, regardless of your representation, you will end up with groupings which you're not happy with simply because those groups don't exist in your high dimensional representation.

Comment: Could you show a small an instance of this algorithm using my datapoints? I think this may be a good alternative, even though it's not exactly what i was trying

Comment: It's getting a bit late tonight, but I have my own question I want to bouny so I'll see if I can whip something up tomorrow

Comment: So i was watching the video, it doesnt maximize separation, which wont work after all. Reason being the trick to use FLD for multiple clusters with only two classes is by summing the standard deviation, which is the dispersion inside the class and comparing with the sum of their means that is the cluster center, and basically the video explains what you said, it wont improve the separability, only give what it is.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're trying to cluster the data based on a particular label, what are you trying to get as an end result? It seems like what you're tying to do is define a spacial transformation that functions more as a classification tool? To simplify what you said, it seems like you're calculating a transformation to exaggerate the separation between datasets which exist in known regions of high d space. That seems reasonable, but from my experience in classification, the idea of "closeness" is often more useful than "farness", but I suppose that depends on the use case.

Comment: also, looking at your code, it seems like you do the math then just plot the first 2 dimensions of your high D space arbitrarily? If that's the case, then that might be to blame: who knows if the most impactfull axis are the first two? SVD, which I mentioned before, calculates which "n" perpendicular eigenvectors most account for the spread in the datasets. You may want to use that as the tool which gets you from highD to 2D before plotting.

Comment: The first observation is very interesting and accurate. by calculating the standard deviation i can minimize the scatter and increase distance by calculating the centre. For the sake of cleanliness i didnt add the eigenvectors explained variance, but i can confirm the first one gives about 90% more or less and the second one gives around 8 percent. In my actual data, that isnt the reproducible example the clusters are overlapping and not going to the same direction

Comment: I guess it comes down to your use case again, if you know for certain that there is actual high dimensional groups that aren't being represented in 2D, and your only goal is to make a plot which views groupings in a human readable 2D plot, then I would recomend t-sne as it's specifically designed for visualizing grouping. If, instead, you know there's some arbitrary plane within your high dimensional space where, if all your data was projected onto it, it would show you what you want, SVD (singular value decomposition) is probably a good bet. Though, it maximizes data spread, not grouping.

Comment: ah, looked through your profile and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62610782/fishers-linear-discriminant-in-python

Comment: Yes, thats an attempt to employ LDA, which is why grouping datapoint won't work, my data will be projected like this: https://imgur.com/a/25piFJB. Which was what somebody asked why wasnt i trying like that, theres the reason, comming from that question. Essentially, this is what my actual data looks like, using that approach: https://imgur.com/a/WCrmPYT. It looks better though, which is the use of Fisher's linear discriminant by calculating std and means.