# Does the naming of columns affect pandas.DataFrame.transform() in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use `python of Python 3.9.13`, `pandas of Version: 1.5.3`, `numpy of Version: 1.24.2`, and `scikit-learn of Version: 1.2.1` . My problem arises [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62610782) @pythonic833 , which shows

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets

X, y = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)
# X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'feat_{i}' for i in range(4)])  #✔
# X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'X{i}' for i in range(4)])      #✔
# X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'c{i}' for i in range(4)])      #✔
X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'x{i}' for i in range(4)])      #✘
# X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'y{i}' for i in range(4)])      #✘
# X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'z{i}' for i in range(4)])      #✘
y = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['labels'])
tot = pd.concat([X,y], axis=1)
tot[:9] #check data first 9 rows

class_means = tot.groupby('labels').mean()
total_mean = X.mean()
x_mi = tot.transform(lambda x: x - class_means.loc[x['labels']], axis=1).drop('labels', 1)

#replace .as_matrix() with .values in python 3.X 
def kronecker_and_sum(df, weights):
    S = np.zeros((df.shape[1], df.shape[1]))
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        x_m = row.values.reshape(df.shape[1],1)
        S += weights[idx]*np.dot(x_m, x_m.T)
    return S

S_w = kronecker_and_sum(x_mi, 150*[1])
S_w
mi_m = class_means.transform(lambda x: x - total_mean, axis=1)
S_b = kronecker_and_sum(mi_m, 3*[50])
S_b
```

The original codes runs well (just replace `.as_matrix()` with `.values` in python 3.X for the `kronecker_and_sum` function part). However, once I change `X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'feat_{i}' for i in range(4)])`  to such as `X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'x{i}' for i in range(4)])` (which is usual in statistics to use `x1,x2,x3,...`), **an error** occurs for `x_mi` as

```
>>> x_mi = tot.transform(lambda x: x - class_means.loc[x['labels']], axis=1).drop('labels', 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 9407, in transform
    result = op.transform()
  File "D:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 218, in transform
    return obj.T.transform(func, 0, *args, **kwargs).T
  File "D:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 9407, in transform
    result = op.transform()
  File "D:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 256, in transform
    raise ValueError("Function did not transform")
ValueError: Function did not transform
```

Some simple tests are given below (which ✔ for ok and ✘ for errors):

```
X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'feat_{i}' for i in range(4)])  #✔
# X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'X{i}' for i in range(4)])      #✔
# X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'c{i}' for i in range(4)])      #✔
# X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'x{i}' for i in range(4)])      #✘
# X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'y{i}' for i in range(4)])      #✘
# X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[f'z{i}' for i in range(4)])      #✘
```

which makes me wonder if **the naming of columns affect pandas.DataFrame.transform() in Python**!

===============================================================

More weirdly , I directly use the online iris data from [the UCI machine learning repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris) other than the `sklearn.datasets` with the `✔` naming given above, **new errors** for `S_w` and `S_b` occur as

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"
iris = pd.read_csv(url, header=None)
iris.shape
iris.head() 

X = pd.DataFrame(iris.iloc[:,0:4].values, columns=[f'feat_{i}' for i in range(4)])  #✔
y = pd.DataFrame(iris.iloc[:,4].values, columns=['labels'])
tot = pd.concat([X,y], axis=1)

class_means = tot.groupby('labels').mean()
total_mean = X.mean()
x_mi = tot.transform(lambda x: x - class_means.loc[x['labels']], axis=1).drop('labels', 1)

#replace .as_matrix() with .values in python 3.X 
def kronecker_and_sum(df, weights):
    S = np.zeros((df.shape[1], df.shape[1]))
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        x_m = row.values.reshape(df.shape[1],1)
        S += weights[idx]*np.dot(x_m, x_m.T)
    return S

S_w = kronecker_and_sum(x_mi, 150*[1])

>>> S_w = kronecker_and_sum(x_mi, 150*[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in kronecker_and_sum
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' output from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'

mi_m = class_means.transform(lambda x: x - total_mean, axis=1)

S_b = kronecker_and_sum(mi_m, 3*[50])

>>> S_b = kronecker_and_sum(mi_m, 3*[50])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in kronecker_and_sum
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

which makes very confused! **Are there any bugs in my codes or Do I igonre anything? How to amend them?**